# No sound Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: sound

When powering on my PC with Ubuntu 17.04 I don't have any sound. If I go to system tools/preferences/settings and just open sound menu I get back sound. In sound menu I have two devices for sound output:
1.) HDMI/Display Port-RV710/730 HDMI Audio (Radeon HD 4000 Series)
2.) Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio

I have sound turned ON, volume on 100%, when I test speakers I get sound with 1.) device.

Here is output of `lspci | grep -i audio` command:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
```

Alsamixer command results: 
Master 34
Headphon 100
PCM 99
Front 100
Front Mi 93
Front Mi 22
Surround 100
Center 100

Comment: please install `pavucontrol`, it's an excelent sound manager. Before it, open `alsamixer`at terminal session and look at volume levels for Azalia device. Press F6 to switch among these devices.